# Problema varios temporizadores Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando crear una web que contiene una sección con muchos temporizadores para poder medir el tiempo que se tardan en determinadas tareas. 
El problema lo tengo cuando interacciono con dos temporizadores a la vez, cuando tienes varios contadores funcionando e intentas parar el primero se para el último y el resto sigue corriendo. Mi código:

HTML:

```
<div id="taskModal2" class="col-lg-6">
    <span id="title-Addsubtask">SUBTAREAS (0)</span>
    <div class="subtaskList">
        <i class="si si-bell alertSubtask"></i>
        <input type="checkbox" id="subtaskCheck" name="subtaskCheck" />
        <div class="subtaskTitle">Titulo de la subtarea</div>
        <div><i class="fa fa-play"><span class="subtaskTime">00:00:00</span></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="subtaskList">
        <input type="checkbox" id="subtaskCheck" name="subtaskCheck" />
        <div class="subtaskTitle">Titulo de la subtarea</div>
        <div><i class="fa fa-play"><span class="subtaskTime">00:00:00</span></i></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea type="text" id="inputSubtask" name="inputSubtask" Placeholder="Nueva subtarea"></textarea>
        <div class="mask">
            <div class="buscador">
                <input type="search" class="rectangle-4">
                <i class="si si-magnifier searchIcon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="client-list">
            </div>
            <div class="optionSubmenuOpenTask">
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Change Start To Pause
$(document).on('click', '.fa-play', function(){

    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
    $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
    var aux = $(this);

    var horas = $(this).children('.subtaskTime').html().split(':');

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Task/startSubtaskTimer',
        type: "post",
        data:{
            'subtaskId' : aux.siblings("#subtaskCheck").data('subtaskid'),
            'employeeId' : $('#employeeId').val()
        },
        success:function(){
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });

    var h = horas[0];
    var m = horas[1];
    var s = horas[2];
    var ht = '';
    var mt = '';
    var st = '';

    cont = setInterval(function(){
            s++;

            if(s == 60)
            {
                s = 00;
                m++;
            }

            if(m == 60)
            {
                m = 00;
                h++;
            }

            ht = '';
            mt = '';
            st = '';

            if(h < 10)
            {
                if(h == 00)
                {
                }else{
                    ht+='0';
                }
            }
            if(m < 10)
            {
                if(m == 00)
                {
                }else{
                    mt+='0';
                }
            }
            if(s < 10){
                st+='0';
            }

            ht+=h;
            mt+=m;
            st+=s;

            aux.children('.subtaskTime').html(ht + ":" + mt + ":" + st);
        }, 1000);
});

// Change Pause To Start
$(document).on('click', '.fa-pause', function(){

    var aux = $(this);
    $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
    $(this).addClass('fa-play');

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Task/stopSubtaskTimer',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'subtaskId'  : aux.siblings("#subtaskCheck").data('subtaskid'),
            'employeeId' : $('#employeeId').val(),
            'time'       : aux.children('.subtaskTime').html()
        }
    });

    clearInterval(cont);
});
```

PHP:

```
public function startSubtaskTimer(){

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $subtaskId  = $_POST['subtaskId'];
    $employeeId = $_POST['employeeId'];

    $statement = "SELECT * FROM be_task_subtask_time WHERE subtaskId = '$subtaskId' && employeeId = '$employeeId'";

    $query = $this->db->query($statement);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $data = array(
            'state' => '1'
        );

        $this->db->where('subtaskId', $subtaskId);
        $this->db->where('employeeId', $employeeId);
        $this->db->update('be_task_subtask_time', $data);

    }else{

        $data = array(
            'subtaskId'     => $subtaskId,
            'employeeId'    => $employeeId,
            'state'         => '1',
            'time'          => '00:00:00',
        );

        $this->db->insert('be_task_subtask_time', $data);
    }

}

public function stopSubtaskTimer(){

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $subtaskId  = $_POST['subtaskId'];
    $employeeId = $_POST['employeeId'];
    $time       = $_POST['time'];

    $data = array(
        'state' => '0',
        'time'  => $time,
    );

    $this->db->where('subtaskId', $subtaskId);
    $this->db->where('employeeId', $employeeId);
    $this->db->update('be_task_subtask_time', $data);

}
```

¿Alguna idea de donde viene el problema?

Comment: cont es una variable global que sobreescribes cada vez que hace click en un .fa-play con lo que al hacer clearInterval estás limpiando el último contador. Deberías tener un array con tantos contadores como .fa-play tengas y apagar/encender el adecuado en cada caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás almacenando correctamente los identificadores de procesos devueltos por [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), por lo que sólo se queda almacenado en `cont` la última asignación.

Como solución puedes asignar dicho valor a una propiedad del elemento del DOM que recibe los eventos de clic del ratón.

En el código he usado `$(this).get(0).cont = setInterval(...` para acceder mediante [`$jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) al elemento del DOM y allí almacenar en la propiedad `cont` el valor devuelto.

Durante la pausa vuelvo a acceder al valor almacenado para parar el intervalo planificado con `clearInterval($(this).get(0).cont);`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo funcional (haz click en ambos temporizadores y pruébalo tú mismo):

```js
// Change Start To Pause
base_url = '';
$(document).on('click', '.fa-play', function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
    $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
    var aux = $(this);

    var horas = $(this).children('.subtaskTime').html().split(':');

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Task/startSubtaskTimer',
        type: "post",
        data:{
            'subtaskId' : aux.siblings("#subtaskCheck").data('subtaskid'),
            'employeeId' : $('#employeeId').val()
        },
        success:function(){
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });

    var h = horas[0];
    var m = horas[1];
    var s = horas[2];
    var ht = '';
    var mt = '';
    var st = '';

    $(this).get(0).cont = setInterval(function(){
            s++;

            if(s == 60)
            {
                s = 00;
                m++;
            }

            if(m == 60)
            {
                m = 00;
                h++;
            }

            ht = '';
            mt = '';
            st = '';

            if(h < 10)
            {
                if(h == 00)
                {
                }else{
                    ht+='0';
                }
            }
            if(m < 10)
            {
                if(m == 00)
                {
                }else{
                    mt+='0';
                }
            }
            if(s < 10){
                st+='0';
            }

            ht+=h;
            mt+=m;
            st+=s;

            aux.children('.subtaskTime').html(ht + ":" + mt + ":" + st);
        }, 1000);
});

// Change Pause To Start
$(document).on('click', '.fa-pause', function(){
    var aux = $(this);
    $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
    $(this).addClass('fa-play');

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + 'Task/stopSubtaskTimer',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'subtaskId'  : aux.siblings("#subtaskCheck").data('subtaskid'),
            'employeeId' : $('#employeeId').val(),
            'time'       : aux.children('.subtaskTime').html()
        }
    });

    clearInterval($(this).get(0).cont);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="taskModal2" class="col-lg-6">
    <span id="title-Addsubtask">SUBTAREAS (0)</span>
    <div class="subtaskList">
        <i class="si si-bell alertSubtask"></i>
        <input type="checkbox" id="subtaskCheck" name="subtaskCheck" />
        <div class="subtaskTitle">Titulo de la subtarea</div>
        <div><i class="fa fa-play"><span class="subtaskTime">00:00:00</span></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="subtaskList">
        <input type="checkbox" id="subtaskCheck" name="subtaskCheck" />
        <div class="subtaskTitle">Titulo de la subtarea</div>
        <div><i class="fa fa-play"><span class="subtaskTime">00:00:00</span></i></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea type="text" id="inputSubtask" name="inputSubtask" Placeholder="Nueva subtarea"></textarea>
        <div class="mask">
            <div class="buscador">
                <input type="search" class="rectangle-4">
                <i class="si si-magnifier searchIcon"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="client-list">
            </div>
            <div class="optionSubmenuOpenTask">
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```